# How to Change an image in 2nd View Controller using a Button in 1st View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have stetted up switch in my First View Controller and assigned the following action to it :-

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var playerNum1Button: UIButton!
  
@IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!
 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      self.toggleSwitch.setOn(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "toggleState"), animated: true)

}

@IBAction func numPlayers1(_ sender: Any) {
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "3to8segue", sender: self)
}
IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    
    if (toggleSwitch.isOn == true) {
        
        Image.image = UIImage(named: "Night")
        
    }
    else {
        
        Image.image = UIImage(named: "background")
        
    }
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "toggleState")
    
}
```

It is Able to change the image in the First View Controller. But, how can I get that switch to change the image in 2nd View controller as well when it is turned on? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Send the image name to the second view controller. Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have looked on that solution before, but it's using sugues to transfer data. I want to change the image in the 2nd view controller by the click of a button in 1st View Controller

Comment: If you want to trigger an action then use delegate pattern or observer pattern but are really both view controllers active at the same time?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I guess I found the way. I am gonna use override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {} function to set the image on another view controller using delegates.

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7, You got your output if yes it's okay else you can use protocol-delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notification Center

Example:
In FirstViewController:

```
@IBAction func onPressButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "pressedButton")
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: "changeImageBackground", object: nil)
}
```

In SecondViewController:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(target: self, selector: #selector(didChangeImageBackground), name: "changeImageBackground", object: nil)

@objc func didChangeImageBackground() {
    let changed = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "pressedButton")
    if changed {
    // image when pressed
    } else {
    // image when haven't pressed
    }
}
```